# How to count records and it's numerical value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am looking for the best way to count records in an underlying table (or query) and allow one to capture that number on the active form.  In short, I would like to create an object on my form which tells the users which record out of how many he is currently looking at (e.g. This is record 3 of 6)

I know how to use the record count function but am having difficulty in transfering that number to an object on my form.

Comment: Doesn't Access already have [something like that](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/access-2003-for/0596006659/httpatomoreillycomsourceoreillyimages2038290.png.jpg)?

Comment: Yes it does (you are referring to the property which allows you to display the navigation buttons and the record count at the bottom).  I am looking for the way to allow for me to rebuild those functions to give me more flexibility and variety with the buttons (controls)

Comment: Ah, I see, you are looking to customize and control the look and feel instead of relying on the one supplied. Let me put a quick example code together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my form I placed a label and called it lblRecords:

On the Form's Current event, Form's CurrentRecord to get the current record number. Although `DCount` is used below, please read through http://www.fontstuff.com/mailbag/qaccess04.htm for examples better than `DCount` to count number of records.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.lblRecords.Caption = "Record " & Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & DCount("ID", "Table1")
End Sub
```

Using [ADODB](http://www.slxdeveloper.com/page.aspx?action=viewarticle&articleid=33), a record count can also be obtained.

**EDIT**

To get recordcount of the datasource bound to the form, one can do this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.lblRecords.Caption = "Record " & Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & RecordCount()
End Sub


Function RecordCount() As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim RecordsClone As Object

    Set RecordsClone = Me.RecordsetClone
    RecordsClone.MoveLast
    RecordCount = RecordsClone.RecordCount
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    RecordCount = "NA"

End Function
```

If the form is bound to a query that shows only a small subset of records from a table, `Function RecordCount()` will show correct information of the number of records.

But what if the data source of the form is changed dynamically using VBA? The above function will still work correctly. Here's an example of how one can change the data source of the form dynamically.

```
Public Sub ChangeFormQuery()
    Form_Form1.RecordSource = "select * from table1 where [id] between 3 and 4"
    Form_Form1.Requery
    Form_Form1.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! This will be reviewed thoroughly the first chance i get and then I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Zedfoxus. This is absolutely what I need. I have an issue with this solution however, the form where I am building this, on the load event queries a table.  The solution you provided me above includes all records in the table.  What I need is the DCount function to only consider records in the query. I am sure this is possible but I cant figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Me.etcRecordNumber.Caption = "Record " & Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & DCount("ID", "tblCompetency06") WHERE [tblcompetency].[teamID]= '" & me.teamid & "'"

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua Edited the answer with code that will help with the case you described

Answer (score 0):

In alternative to using the DCount function, the following is an optimal solution using the label called 'etcRecordNumber' :

```
RC = Form_frmStaticDataSkills03.Recordset.RecordCount
RN = Form_frmStaticDataSkills03.CurrentRecord

Me.etcRecordNumber.Caption = "This is record " & RN & " of " & RC
```